# Output csv file SQL

Tags: sql-server, csv

Here is the code I have so far:

```
DECLARE @bcpCommand varchar(2000)   
DECLARE @query varchar(2000)

SET @query = 'select job_description from [mainDB].[myschema].[table]'
SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp " ' + @query + ' "  queryout "c:\test.csv" -T -c -t,'''
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

When I run this, I get the following message:

> NULL
>   Starting copy...
>   1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file.
>   Total received: 1000 1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file.
>   Total received: 2000 1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file.
>   Total received: 3000 1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file.
>   Total received: 4000 1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file.
>   Total received: 5000 1000 rows successfully bulk-copied to host-file.
>   Total received: 6000
>   6564 rows copied.
>   Network packet size (bytes): 4096
>   Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 16     Average : (410250.00
>   rows per sec.)

The file doesn't exist in the c drive though. Why doesn't the file show up in the c drive? Am I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: If you run this on a remote SQL Server - the file should be in the (remote) **server's** `C:` drive - not your local harddisk's `C:` drive....

Comment: I'm a bit new in creating csv files in sql server. Where exactly can I extract this file and is there anyway to put it in my local c drive?

Comment: As I said - it's output to the server machine's `C:` drive - you need to copy it from there. And **no**, you cannot redirect the output directly to your local `C:` drive.

Comment: or you could ask it to export to a share on your machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will output to the C drive of the server, not the client machine.  Is it possible you're looking at your C drive and not the server's?

Answer (score 0):

For those who cant' have access to the server's c drive, I found a way to retrieve the csv file and insert it into a temporary table

```
BULK
INSERT tempTable
FROM 'c:\filename.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO

select * from tempTable
```